# Error in loading data from database to gridview using ajax json C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I'm trying to load data from database to `gridview` while scrolling page.It work like this

1)Intially when the page is loaded gridview display 10 data  form the `database`(works fine)

2)while scrolling `gridview` display a image for loading  and that time a server side function is called by using  ajax `json` method for loading next 5 data from database

3)after successfully hitting this function the javascript removes the image for loading and appends the gridview with next 5 data.

Now the problem is after removing the image the gridview shows the first data from the database again and again in the gridview for the next 5 times . Please Help..

C#

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            newscontainer.DataSource = GetNewsPageWise(1, 10);
            newscontainer.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public static DataSet GetNewsPageWise(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        string constring = "server=***;uid=***;pwd=******;database=*******";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[GetNewsPageWise]"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", pageIndex);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", pageSize);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PageCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(ds, "popnews");
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable("PageCount");
                        dt.Columns.Add("PageCount");
                        dt.Rows.Add();
                        dt.Rows[0][0] = cmd.Parameters["@PageCount"].Value;
                        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                        return ds;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetCustomers(int pageIndex)
    {
        //Added to similate delay so that we see the loader working
        //Must be removed when moving to production
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return GetNewsPageWise(pageIndex, 5).GetXml();
    }

}
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageIndex = 1;
var pageCount;
$(function () {
    //Remove the original GridView header
    $("[id$=newscontainer] tr").eq(0).remove();
});
//Load GridView Rows when DIV is scrolled
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        GetRecords();
    }
});
//Function to make AJAX call to the Web Method
function GetRecords() {
    pageIndex++;
    if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {

        //Show Loader
        if ($("[id$=newscontainer] .loader").length == 0) {
            var row = $("[id$=newscontainer] tr").eq(0).clone(true);
            row.addClass("loader");
            row.children().remove();
            row.append('<td colspan = "999" style = "background-color:white"> <asp:Image ID="loader" runat="server" Height="50px" ImageUrl="~/Images/loader.gif" Width="51px" /></td>');
            $("[id$=newscontainer]").append(row);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "News.aspx/GetCustomers",
            data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
}


 function OnSuccess(response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
    var customers = xml.find("popnews");
    $("[id$=newscontainer] .loader").remove();
    customers.each(function () {
        var customer = $(this);
        var row = $("[id$=newscontainer] tr").eq(0).clone(true);
        $(".postedon").html(customer.find("newsdate").text());
        $(".news").html(customer.find("news").text());
        $("[id$=newscontainer]").append(row);
    });

    //Hide Loader
    $("#loader").hide();
}
```

Stored Procedure Used

```
            SET ANSI_NULLS ON
            GO
            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
             GO
            CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNewsPageWise]
             @PageIndex INT = 1
                ,@PageSize INT = 10
               ,@PageCount INT OUTPUT
                 AS
                BEGIN
               SET NOCOUNT ON;
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                (
                   ORDER BY [newsid] ASC
                 )AS RowNumber
                   ,[newsid]
                   ,[news]
                  ,[newsdate]
                    ,[newstime]
                    INTO #Results
                  FROM [popnews]

                   DECLARE @RecordCount INT
                    SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #Results

                 SET @PageCount = CEILING(CAST(@RecordCount AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) /            
                 CAST(@PageSize AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))
                    PRINT       @PageCount

                        SELECT * FROM #Results
                       WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 
                         AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

                      DROP TABLE #Results
                         END
```

Comment: i think the problem is not in the AJAX, try to put debug point in GetNewsPageWise() and check the content of ds which returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data is a string, `data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',`, should be
 `data: {pageIndex: pageIndex}`
Please make sure your ajax request has been sent to server and you can get proper response. You can check in dev tool in chrome or firebug.

And, you didn't paste `onSuccess` function. As you said, the callback function didn't work properly to add new data. Maybe the reason is in there.

**[updated]**
Your success function is:

```
customers.each(function () {
    var customer = $(this);
    var row = $("[id$=newscontainer] tr").eq(0).clone(true);
    $(".postedon").html(customer.find("newsdate").text()); //problem
    $(".news").html(customer.find("news").text());         //problem
    $("[id$=newscontainer]").append(row);
});
```

in the lines mark as 'problem', you set text for the element has those classes. So all the elements with that calss will be selected.I think what you want is set the data for the cloned row element. Please try:

```
$(".news", row).html(customer.find("news").text());
```

which will find element with class 'news' in the row.

Comment: Now I have pasted the onSuccess function please take a look

Comment: still no luck same problem again

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can see at first site is that in the ajax call you have `dataType: "json"`, but from the web method you are returning a XML formatted result, so the dataType property should be set to "xml".